# How to generate arrays of text files serially?

Tags: python-3.x

aTxt folder has 3000 text files. My code reads these .txt files in a random order like(1.txt,10.txt,1000.txt,...). How can I read these text files serially (like first it read 1.txt then 2.txt and so on upto 3000.txt) and append these text files to an array?

```
from pickle import dump
import glob
textlist = []
textfiles = glob.glob('D:/qrt/aTxt/*.txt')
for x in textfiles:
    x1 = open(x, 'r')
    x2 = x1.read()
    textlist.append(x2)
    x1.close()
dump(textlist, open('textlists.pkl', 'wb'))
```

Comment: please define "the same order as they are in folder" ? do you mean lexical order, creation date, inode number, else ?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean lexical order you can simply sort the list of filepath that you obtained from `glob` using builtin function `sorted()`

```
from pickle import dump
import glob
textlist = []
textfiles = glob.glob('D:/qrt/aTxt/*.txt')
for filepath in sorted(textfiles):
    with open(filepath , 'rt') as finput:
        content = finput.read()
        textlist.append(content)

dump(textlist, open('textlists.pkl', 'wb'))
```